# How to incorporate controllers on a Blazor Hybrid app?

Tags: asp.net, blazor, maui, blazor-hybrid

I'm trying to embed an existing Angular based frontend into a desktop application using Blazor Hybrid.

My startup looks more or less like so:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
builder.Services.AddWindowsFormsBlazorWebView();
var webapp = builder.Build();
webapp.MapGet("/api/testendpoint", () => "test");
webView.HostPage = @"dist\index.html"; 
webView.Services = webapp.Services;
```

Calling /api/endpoint from the webview results in 404: "There is no content at /api/testendpoint". Any ideas how to get controllers working in Blazor Hybrid?

I've tried various configurations of getting WebApplication working. Somehow ASP.Net core was not bootstrapped except for Blazor parts. I've tried using MAUI as well.

Comment: see [Open issue: Support for MAUI runtimes in ASP.Net Core?](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35077). Current status is "Backlog". Observe the last few comments, by people using related technologies that worked in Xamarin: One app moving to Flutter. One app dropping ASP.Net support. One app self-maintaining an older technology that will soon be no longer supported by Microsoft. Decide in your own circumstances whether to wait (an unknown length of time) for Microsoft to fix this or to look elsewhere.

Comment: Clarification: Do you need `ASP.Net Core` or just `.Net Core`, to run Angular? If it is `.Net Core`, then disregard the above comment and link. Or to put it another way, if you only need "front end" logic, not the "server" side of ASP.Net Core, there might be some way to get the part of Angular you need working. Maybe discuss with whatever forum or support exists for Angular. "Blazor Hybrid" is a "front end" (client) technology.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I need ASP.Net Core (Web API). That's a shame then, I was hoping to use ASP.Net Core in a desktop app similar to Electron but  without having open TCP ports..

Comment: Microsoft’s answer to that is Maui Blazor. Roughly similar in concept to what it would be like to code for Electron, for use in an app instead of backend. If I understand correctly. Coding in Web languages, but not a web server.